# What Operating System Provides Easy and Complete Software Uninstallation?

Tags: windows, linux, linux-distribution, operating-system, uninstall

I want to be able to easily and completely remove a program/package and everything associated with it: all dependencies, all configuration files, all data files, and all traces in logs and $HOME (I heard changes could occur here). Basically, something where, after uninstallation, the system is the exact same as it was before uninstallation. Are there any operating systems that can do this?

I'm currently a Windows user, and I'm curious about Linux. I would switch to Linux, but it sounds like it cannot do what I am asking above. I know about `apt-get purge package`, `apt-get --purge autoremove`, and `apt purge --autoremove package`, but it sounds like these still leave remnants in logs and $HOME. I want to leave no trace after uninstallation.

*I'm trying to follow the [question asking guide](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/208), so here's a list of constraints, in order of importance:*

1. Must meet requirements in first paragraph.
2. I will use it as my main OS for general purpose and school.

Comment: In Windows, the best you can do is use portable software.  But Windows keeps all sorts of logs and records of almost everything you do, so even with portable software there will likely be indications of what software was used on the system.  I'm not currently enough of a Linux expert to provide accurate details for that OS, but hopefully someone else here will know and be able to recommend a specific Linux distro that will meet your requirements.

Comment: You're correct with the `$HOME` assumption – and even an `apt purge` wouldn't touch any logs etc. But you probably could achieve your goals by "jailing" applications (just quoting hear-say here, didn't experiment with it myself and especially don't know about graphical components). Keywords for that would be e.g. `chroot` and `firejail`. The idea is putting the app into a [Sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) it cannot escape – so all its files are inside the box, and removing them would just mean removing the box.

Comment: The only software system that more or less works this way are docker images. Then encapsulate everything inside and if you delete an docker image everything is gone (just may be some cached docker images may remain). If you want to burn really everything use a virtual machine and to "uninstall" just delete the while VM.